# How do I make a field contain multiple options in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
create database LeagueCharacters;
use LeagueCharacters;
create table champions (Cname VARCHAR(20),class VARCHAR(20),role set 
("top","jng","mid","bot","sup"));
ALTER TABLE champions ADD PRIMARY KEY (Cname);
INSERT INTO champions(Cname, class, role) VALUES 
("ChoGath","Tank","top"),
("Vayne","Marksman","top"),
("Jax","Tank","top"),
("Yone","Assassin","mid"),
("Veigar","Mage","mid"),
("Amumu","Tank","jng"),
("Vi","Tank","jng"),
("Nunu & Willump","Tank","jng"),
("Diana","Assassin","jng"),
("Kalista","Marksman","bot"),
("Miss Fortune","Marksman","bot"),
("Senna","Marksman","sup"),
("Morgana","Mage","sup"),
("Blitzcrank","Tank","sup"),
("Seraphine","Cleric","sup"),
("Soraka","Cleric","sup"),
("Leona","Tank","sup");
```

Okay, so I've managed to create the table and select characters from it as I want. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE class = "Cleric" ORDER BY Cname;
```

Gives me all of the clerics in alphabetical order. However, I'd like to be able to make it so that the same character can be in multiple classes or roles.

For example, I'd like both:

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE role = "bot";
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE role = "top";
```

to list "Vayne" in their output. Also, I'd like both:

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE class = "Cleric";
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE class = "Marksman";
```

To list "Senna".

One approach I thought of was to replace the role with an abbreviation (e.g. "tb" for "top and bot") but the problem here is I then can't check which role a character has as

```
SELECT role FROM champions WHERE Cname = "Vayne";
```

would give me "tb" which isn't clear. Also if I wanted ALL the characters that can bot, whether they have a secondary class or not, it seems like this would require some spaghetti code which isn't ideal.

So yeah, is there a way I can put multiple different values into the same field without resorting to abbreviations or spaghetti code?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Create a different primary key: `ALTER TABLE champions ADD PRIMARY KEY (Cname, class, role);`  You might want to do this via a different table, if this table is meant to contain one row per character.

Comment: I think I understand. So separate tables for all the roles and classes and then one table with all the character's info in?

Comment: Something like that.  But this will depend whether there's a relationship between role and class or only between character and class, then between character and role, independently.  The relationships are not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! There is a correlation (clerics tend to be sup, marksmen tend to be bot) but they are independent in there are some characters in each class that play each role.

Comment: As I see you use SET datatype incorrectly, you use it as ENUM datatype...

Comment: I'm not familiar with ENUM yet, but I'll search it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

```
create table champions (
  Cname VARCHAR(100),
  class VARCHAR(200),
  `role` set('top','jng','mid','bot','sup')
);
ALTER TABLE champions ADD PRIMARY KEY (Cname);
INSERT INTO champions(Cname, class, role) VALUES 
("ChoGath","Tank",'top,bot'),
("Vayne","Marksman,Cleric","top"),
("Jax","Tank","top,bot"),
("Yone","Assassin","mid"),
("Veigar","Mage","mid"),
("Amumu","Tank","jng"),
("Vi","Tank","jng"),
("Nunu & Willump","Tank","jng"),
("Diana","Assassin","jng"),
("Kalista","Marksman","bot"),
("Miss Fortune","Marksman","bot"),
("Senna","Marksman","sup"),
("Morgana","Mage","sup"),
("Blitzcrank","Tank","sup"),
("Seraphine","Cleric","sup"),
("Soraka","Cleric","sup"),
("Leona","Tank","sup")
;
```

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE find_in_set("bot",role);
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE find_in_set("Cleric",class);
```

It works on `set` and `varchar`, but on `set` has better performances.

here the [mysqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/792de0/3)